# hive data gets reset when app is restarted

Tags: flutter, hive, local-storage, flutter-hive

I have stored data in Hive box but whenever i restart the app or kills the app during offline mode i.e when internet conmnection is not there, Data gets resets & shows null error.

```
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter<ProgressList>(ProgressListAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter<VideoList>(VideoListAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter<DashBoard>(DashBoardAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter<CourseDetails>(CourseDetailsAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter<AnnouncementsListData>(AnnouncementsListDataAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter<VideoAssignments>(VideoAssignmentsAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter<LessonDetail>(LessonDetailAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter<CourseQuestions>(CourseQuestionsAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<ProgressList>("box");
  await Hive.openBox<VideoList>("video_box");
  await Hive.openBox<DashBoard>("dashboard_box");
  await Hive.openBox<CourseDetails>("course_box");
  await Hive.openBox<AnnouncementsListData>("announcement_box");
  await Hive.openBox<VideoAssignments>("vfs_feedback_box");
  await Hive.openBox<LessonDetail>("lesson_box");
  await Hive.openBox<CourseQuestions>("questions_box");
  await Hive.openBox("video_record_box");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are passing all parameters of the models to the constructor, for example in the code below

```
@HiveType(typeId: 22)
class WeeklyListModel extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String id;

  @HiveField(1)
  final List<TaskModel> tasks = [];

  WeeklyListModel(this.id);
}
```

The read function of adapter will look like this

```
@override
  WeeklyListModel read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return WeeklyListModel(
      fields[0] as String
    );
  }
```

So the tasks are automatically set to empty list as they can not be passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you're facing this in debug mode, then you probably don't notice the difference between debugging an app and using it in release mode.

Your app may be running fine, if you debug your app on an Android emulator as an example, make sure that whenever you close the emulator, and you want to open it again, make sure that the emulator doesn't clear all phone data whenever you open it again, so it looks like the `Hive` didn't save your data, but actually the emulator set that it will clean all phone data whenever it's launched.

How this is related to `Hive`:

The `Hive` package is a key-value database, which saves its data inside files inside your device, so clearing all phone data will normally clear those files.

You need to try your app in a real device for making sure that your data is saved, and I would recommend to test if first in a release mode version.